# Java undefined generic type

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a generic class which extends another generic class.

The abstract class has 2 type parameters, but I need only one in my functions.

Is it save to just assign it a random like String type, or are there any drawbacks to this?

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo<T, B>
{
   public abstract void read(T item);
}

public class LittleFoo extends AbstractFoo<byte[], String>
{
   @Override
   public void read(byte[] item)
   {
      // work here
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want just one generic parameter, then why you have declared 2 at the first place?

Comment: Because I have multiple classes inheriting from this one by design. Only a few special classes only need 1 parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there really isn't any drawback to this, and it seems like a simple way to do it in my opinion.

Also, you might want to consider using *composition* instead of *extension*. For example, take a look at the [`HashSet` implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashSet.java.html) from `java.util`:

```
87   public class HashSet<E>
88       extends AbstractSet<E>
89       implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
90   {
91       static final long serialVersionUID = -5024744406713321676L;
92   
93       private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;
94   
95       // Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
96       private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
```

A `HashSet` is basically a `HashMap`, but only considers the set of keys (hence the dummy variable `PRESENT`, which is just a placeholder). You could perhaps do something similar.

Comment: Very informative answer, thanks. Actually I'm using both, my classes have other children of AbstractFoo as fields.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use `java.lang.Void` instead of `String`.